# Laravel 5.2 - Tips to make this better?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I kinda feel weird about the way I fetch models on Eloquent. I would like to know if there's any way I can make my current code look better? Here is it:
[image]

Yes I can loop to get less codes but the way I fetch models is my main concern, I mean is there anyway I can reduce the calls to 1 instead of 12?

Thanks!

Comment: can you tell me, which fields you are going to fetch? there many ways available... one is most common and workable for select drop down is
`Info::lists('name','id')->all()` it will produce results like this 
`[1=>Jan, 2=>Feb, 3=>Mar ...... ]`

Comment: I only want the 'encoded' field tho..

Comment: Can you provide your database. I can offer another way which uses the `GROUP BY` of MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you can do this `Info::get(['encoded']);` you will get the array of encoded field, loop through and make it according to your requirements.

More specific follow this.

***Edited***

```
$result =Info::whereMonth('encoded','>=','01')->whereMonth('encoded','<=','12')->get()->first();
```

here `->first();` will remove the array into array structure. will return `[.....]` instead `[0=>[....] ]`

so loop your result

```
$months = [];

foreach($result as $month){

  if($month == '01'){
   $months['jan'] = $month;
  }

  if($month == '02'){
   $months['feb'] = $month;
  }

  if($month == '03'){
   $months['mar'] = $month;
  }
//and so on
}
```

Comment: will this query once? based on your code, it will populate `encoded` ranging from 01 to 12, but how can i finally add it into an array?

Comment: there are multiple ways, you can use foreach loop and also array index
you really want to use array like this `$months['jan']= ... $months['feb']=` ?

Comment: Exactly. How do you map it from the queried model?

Comment: @Jim see me updated answer, I just give you concept/idea, you use it according to your results/requirements

Answer (score 1):

@Qazi to make the foreach shorter and less if statements lets do some refactoring

```
 $months_keys = ['jan','feb','mar',....];
 $months = []

 foreach($result as $month){
     $key = $months_keys[(int)$month - 1];
     $months[$key] = $month;
 }
```